# How to use golang bleve search results?

Tags: go, full-text-search, bleve

I am new to Go and [Bleve](http://www.blevesearch.com/) (sorry if I'm asking trivial things…). This search engine seems to be really nice, but I am getting stuck when it comes to deal with my search results.

Let's say we have a struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Bio  string `json:"bio"`
}
```

Now, we extract data from the database (using sqlx lib):

```
rows := []Person{}
db.Select(&rows, "SELECT * FROM person")
```

...and index it:

```
index.Index, err = bleve.Open("index.bleve")

batch := index.Index.NewBatch()

i := 0
for _, row := range rows {
    rowId := fmt.Sprintf("%T_%d", row, row.ID)
    batch.Index(rowId, row)

    i++
    if i > 100 {
        index.Index.Batch(batch)
        i = 0
    }
}
```

Now we have our index created. It works great.

Using the [bleve command line utility](http://www.blevesearch.com/docs/bleve_query/), it returns data correctly:

```
bleve query index.bleve doe

3 matches, showing 1 through 3, took 27.767838ms
    1. Person_68402 (0.252219)
    Name
        Doe
    Bio
        My name is John Doe!

    2. ...
```

Here we see that bleve has stored `Name` and `Bio` fields.

Now I want to do it to access it from my code!

```
query := bleve.NewMatchAllQuery()
searchRequest := bleve.NewSearchRequest(query)
searchResults, _ := index.Index.Search(searchRequest)

fmt.Println(searchResults[0].ID) // <- This works
```

But I don't only want the ID and then query the database to get the rest of the date. To [avoid hitting database](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/best_practices.html#avoid-hitting-the-database), I would like to be able to do something like:

```
fmt.Println(searchResults[0].Bio) // <- This doesn't work :(
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every hit in the search result is a [DocumentMatch](https://godoc.org/github.com/blevesearch/bleve/search#DocumentMatch). You can see in the documentation that `DocumentMatch` has `Fields` which is a `map[string]interface{}` and can be accessed as follows:

```
searchResults.Hits[0].Fields["Bio"].(string)
```

Bleve doesn't include the document's fields in the results by default. You must provide a list of the fields you'd like returned to `SearchRequest.Fields` (the argument to `index.Search`). Alternatively, you can set

```
searchRequest.Fields = []string{"*"}
```

to return all fields.

Comment: Thank you very much Moshe, it works like a charm! Fields are located in Hits, so I had to do a searchResults.Hits[0].Fields["Bio"] to get it.

Comment: @user650108 Good catch ;-)

Comment: 「Alternatively, you can pass []string{"*"} to return all fields.」, pass to where?

Comment: Just for note. Pass the Hits ID to index.Document will get fields, also if setup  the index Internal, use index.GetInternal with Hits ID will get the original struct.